# Order By on the Basis of Dictint Group count

Tags: .net, database, linq

I've to bring those documents from the table which have a specific word, and I've to use order by so that those documents which have highest count comes first. for example

Document 1: this is a school. this is my school
Document 2: this is our school
Document 3: my school is this this this

Now if I use

`select Document.Id, Document_Word.Location 
 from Document, Document_Word, word
 where Document.Id = Document_Word.Document_Id
 and Document_Word.Word_Id = Word.Id 
 and Word.Word = 'this'`

Reault is
 [image: result]

I want to order by Descending on the basis of count of unique id... I actually need LINQ query for this issue

This is my database schema

[image: Schema]

hopefully I've stated my problem clearly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample using Entity Framework,

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var documentEntities = (from document in context.Documents
        join document_word in context.Document_Word on document equals document_word.Document
        join word in context.Words on document_word.Word equals word
        where word.Word1 == "this" // Filter for word = "this"
        group document_word by document_word.Document.Id into documentWordGroup // First group Document_Words by document Id so that we can sort based on the Id count
        let IdCount = documentWordGroup.Count() // store the count into a variable IdCount
        orderby IdCount descending // here we sort by the IdCount
        select documentWordGroup).ToArray() // select the sorted Document_Word groups
        .SelectMany(dw => dw); // combine the groups into a single array of Document_Words

    //Display the result in the Console output
    Console.WriteLine("ID" + "\t" + "Location");
    foreach (var document in documentEntities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(document.Document.Id + "\t" + document.Location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its perfect .... I'd write SQL statement and was trying to convert it in LINQ,  
Stay blessed

Comment: Thanks for confirming... Glad to know that its working for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Linq query.

```
var res = (from document in Documents
    join document_word in DocumentWords on document.Id equals document_word.Document_Id
    join word in Words on document_word.WordId equals word.wordId
    group document by document.Id
    into g
    let IdCount = g.Count()
    orderby IdCount descending
    select new {Key = g.Key, Items = g.Distinct().ToList()}).
    SelectMany(x => x.Items).ToList();
```

This groups by the document Id and does a descending sort and returns the groups.
Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: yup error on `g.Count(x => x.Id)` it says can't implicitly convert type `int` to `bool`

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Search_Engine.Models.Document] ToList[Document](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Search_Engine.Models.Document])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I have used Linq to Objects to demonstrate how you can group to achieve the desired result. You have to translate this so that Linq to Entities recognizes this. I have further updates the answer and this works for Linq to objects.

Comment: same exception.. :( actually I'm not able to understand the `into` in `group by` that's why unable to modify it... I'm using the same syntax

Comment: please help me I'm stuck. I've search a lot but now problem is just in the second part i.e. `g.Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: I am working on a solution using entity framework... I will post another answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SQL query will be helpful for you or somebody else (perhaps you can translate it into linq)

First we need count(ID). Lets find it:

```
SELECT *,count(ID) FROM document GROUP BY ID order by count(ID)
```

Then we can inner join above table with document:

```
SELECT * FROM document
INNER JOIN ( SELECT *,count(ID) FROM document GROUP BY ID order by count(ID) ) y
ON document.ID=y.ID
```

This code will return ID sorted by number of different locations.

Comment: Nope ... it says **The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views**

Comment: Okay, maybe try without ORDER BY and see result? Then you can write count(ID) as count and order by count desc when you exec this view.

Comment: if we use group by clause then repeating terms become one unit.. this doesn't required... for example in this case I only get (id--count) (1----2) (2----1) (3----3)